# 1600 memory not working on 1333 motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

I just bought a Kingston HyperX blu clocked at 1600 and installed it on my motherboard that can support up to 1333 ddr3 memory but it **acts as if there is no memory installed.**

It tries to turn on, but does nothing...

The manufacturer states that it...

> Support for DDR3 1333(O.C.)/1066/800 MHz memory modules

They also state that it can support...

> up to 8 GB of system memory

I know that installing faster memory on a slower board will downclock the memory, but it doesn't even boot up.

In the meantime, i'll try physically cleaning the slots...

edit: I've tried cleaning it already, no luck.

memory:

http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KHX1600C9D3B1_4G.pdf
http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/hyperx/blu/

board:

http://www.gigabyte.ph/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3997#sp

Comment: Please check http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-g41m-combo.pdf for the memory compatibility scpecs. It's at the Support and Downloads regarding your motherboard.

Comment: @SubaruTashiro You purchase memory that is not supporte dby your hardware.

Comment: i exchanged it for another memory from a generic chinese brand - same speed and size. It's also not supported but somehow works. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You bought 1600 Mhz RAM but the board only supports 1333. That'd be your issue. If the board doesn't support the speed it won't work period (not downclock). The only time the board would downclock was if you had two different speeds.